# How can I map stream with grouping?

Tags: java, mapping, java-stream

I have a **very long** stream of children.

```java
// ordered by parent.id / child.id
Stream<Child> childStream;
```

say,

```
Child(id = 1, parent(id = 1))
Child(id = 2, parent(id = 1))
Child(id = 3, parent(id = 2))
Child(id = 4, parent(id = 2))
Child(id = 5, parent(id = 3))
```

Each `Child` has a parent.

```java
class Child {
    Parent parent;
}
```

Now, how can I map the stream into a stream of `Family`?

```java
class Family {
    Parent parent;
    List<Child> children;
}
```

I already know `Collectors.groupingBy`, but the stream is so long that collecting them all into a `Map` is not applicable.

Comment: @YCF_L If the `Map<Parent, List<Child>>` holds only one entry, it's ok. The stream is so big.

Comment: Where does this stream come from? Define "very long".

Comment: You have to process all of the `Child` instances of the `Stream` in order to construct `Family` instances. Even if you only want to obtain the first `Family` of the `Stream<Family>`, you can't avoid processing the entire `Stream<Child>`.

Comment: What are the `Parent` and `Child` types? Looks like a tree to me. That would require some post-processing after `groupingBy`, or alternatively a custom collector. Furthermore, is it guaranteed that the input list is sorted as in your example (breadth-first)? Otherwise, there is no way grouping lazily, as there might be a child of the first child at the very end of the list.

Comment: @JBNizet The query is from a event log table. The length depends the input recurrence, yet any terminal stanza except reductions is not applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution by [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) if the stream is ordered by parent(id).

```
StreamEx.of(childStream)
        .collapse((a, b) -> a.getParent().getId() == b.getParent().getId(), Collectors.toList())
        .map(cl-> new Family(cl.get(0).getParent(), cl))...;
```

`collapse` is lazy evaluation comparing `groupBy`. For Example, if you only want to get first 5 families, only the children in first 5 families will be loaded, not all.

```
StreamEx.of(childStream)
        .collapse((a, b) -> a.getParent().getId() == b.getParent().getId(), Collectors.toList())
        .map(cl-> new Family(cl.get(0).getParent(), cl))
        .limit(5);
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to group your `Child` instances into `Family` instances, you must process the `Stream`, so a terminal operation is required. You can use `groupingBy` and then transform the resulting `Map` into the `Stream` you need:

```
Stream<Family> families = 
    childStream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Child::getParent))
               .entrySet()
               .stream()
               .map(entry -> new Family(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()));
```

This is assuming your `Family` class has a `Family(Parent parent, List<Child> children)` constructor.

Comment: For this to work Parent must implement equals(), and presumably hashCode()

Comment: @TomDrake That's true.

Comment: @Eran The origin stream is a very long one. Does `groupingBy` take care about this?

Comment: @JinKwon How long is very long? And what do you mean by "take care about this"?